# Delete a Syncfusion SfSchedule appointment

Tags: xamarin.forms, realm, syncfusion, sfschedule

I have a class `Activity` that inherit from `RealmObject`. I am adding it to the realm database and there's a the page that contains a weekly `SfSchedule`. When the user choose an appointment(all the appointment are retrieved from the database using realm) an action sheet pops up and there is an option delete.

```
  private async void Details_CellTapped(object sender, ScheduleTappedEventArgs args) {
     var action = await DisplayActionSheet("More details", "Cancel",null, "Details","Update", "Delete");
     if (action == "Delete") {
        realm = Realm.GetInstance();
        var activityItem = (Activity)args.selectedAppointment;
        realm.Write(() => realm.Remove(activityItem));
     }
  }
```

It give me an error `System.InvalidCastException`: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: DataSource property of Schedule control is of type IEnumerable, so it allows you to perform CRUD operation with AppointmentMapping feature in it. Since you are mentioning about casting exception, could you check with updating the objects with proper boxing (if needed). or else check the same scenario with list view in its selection changed method. That will helps to ensure  the issue with the schedule control.

Comment: check the data type of "args.selectedAppointment" while "Details_CellTapped" event triggered.

Comment: The type of args.selectedAppointment is a object I have to convert it to RealmObject

Answer (score 0):

Please check if that `InvalidCastException` is occurring on the line

`var activityItem = (Activity)args.selectedAppointment;`

it looks like this is nothing to do with Realm.